# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm not sure what's the error on line 2 of my .json file when I try to print console.

```
 {
    "users": [{
        "timestamp": "5/4/2017 8:32:29",
        "name": "Alca",
        "IV": 5,
        "V": 5,
        "VI": 5,
        "I": 2,
        "II": 4,
        "III": 5,
        "VII": 4,
        "Rogue1": 3,
        "Holiday": null
    },{ "timestamp": "5/4/2017 16:28:05",
        "name": "Leon",
        "IV": 1,
        "V": 1,
        "VI": 1,
        "I": 1,
        "II": 1,
        "III": 1,
        "VII": 1,
        "Rogue1": 1,
        "Holiday": 1
    }]
}
```

`var data;
function preload(){
    data = loadJSON('movies.json');
}`

```
function setup() {

noCanvas();
console.log(data);}
```

What's wrong with the colon and how can this be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the error and also how do you print it?

Comment: The end of my code actually has the bracket so I'm still not sure what's the error

Comment: Try removing the quotes from all the object keys. So `users` instead of `"users"`, and for all the others aswell. Not 100% sure they cause the error, but they certainly are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket at the end of "users" property.

```js
{
  "users": [{
      "timestamp": "5/4/2017 8:32:29",
      "name": "Alca",
      "IV": 5,
      "V": 5,
      "VI": 5,
      "I": 2,
      "II": 4,
      "III": 5,
      "VII": 4,
      "Rogue1": 3,
      "Holiday": null
  }], //more code... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
    "users"[{
        "timestamp": "5/4/2017 8:32:29",
        "name": "Alca",
        "IV": 5,
        "V": 5,
        "VI": 5,
        "I": 2,
        "II": 4,
        "III": 5,
        "VII": 4,
        "Rogue1": 3,
        "Holiday": null
    },{ "timestamp": "5/4/2017 16:28:05",
        "name": "Leon",
        "IV": 1,
        "V": 1,
        "VI": 1,
        "I": 1,
        "II": 1,
        "III": 1,
        "VII": 1,
        "Rogue1": 1,
        "Holiday": 1
    }]
}
```

[Copy and paste code in this link](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html)

i think you should remove ":" behind users it not showing syntax error please check on this link..if any query then tell to me.

Comment: If I remove the colon, I'm still getting an error on the [{ at the beginning. Also, when I try to run the file, it gets stuck on "loading"

Comment: I added the preload code to my question. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Can you get any error message in Console or any where? whats error come ?

Answer (score 0):

the correct json is

```
{
  "users": [{
      "timestamp": "5/4/2017 8:32:29",
      "name": "Alca",
      "IV": 5,
      "V": 5,
      "VI": 5,
      "I": 2,
      "II": 4,
      "III": 5,
      "VII": 4,
      "Rogue1": 3,
      "Holiday": null
  },{ "timestamp": "5/4/2017 16:28:05",
    "name": "Leon",
    "IV": 1,
    "V": 1,
    "VI": 1,
    "I": 1,
    "II": 1,
    "III": 1,
    "VII": 1,
    "Rogue1": 1,
    "Holiday": 1
}] 
}
```

You can text JSON Viewer at below link

[JSON VIEWER LINK](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)